# Which is the best way to move o collection of nodes?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In my game I need a Label with one character with a background and a border. To Achieve this I create this code with a SKLabelNode, SKShapeNode and SKSpriteNode:

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
           
       let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold")
       label.text = "H";
       label.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
       label.fontSize = 120;
       label.userInteractionEnabled = false
        
        let background = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.4), size: CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width*1.2, label.frame.size.height*1.2))
        background.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        background.name = "bkg"
        background.addChild(label)
        label.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:-label.frame.size.height/2)
        
        let border = SKShapeNode(path: CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(-(background.frame.size.width/2), -(background.frame.size.height/2), background.frame.size.width, background.frame.size.height), nil))
        border.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        border.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        border.lineWidth = 5.0
        border.userInteractionEnabled = false
        background.addChild(border)
        
        
        self.addChild(background)
        
        
        
    }
```

I looks like this:

[image]

Then I need to move this collection of nodes. I tried to achieve this that way:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
            
            if touchedNode.name == "bkg" {
                touchedNode.position = location
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't move smoothly and It's hard to tap on this.

I don't know if I change the way I build the label (with 3 nodes) or I change the way I tried to move it.

Is there a best way to move a collection of nodes?

Comment: The way you are building seems good enough. I think the problem is how you move the backgroundNode.

Answer (score 2):

If you add all of the nodes to a singular **parent node**, you could move that parent node and then all three of your existing nodes would move too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cal. How can I do that ? Should I subclass a node and put all stuff inside this new class ?

Comment: I believe you can add a child node to any other node in SpriteKit. Try creating a generic `SKNode` and then adding these nodes as it's children using `parent.addChild(child)`.